# swift ui http request with http status code

Tags: swift, swiftui

What I want to do is if the http status code is 200 than add it to success, otherwise failure.

```
func saveUser(account: String, password: String,confirmPassword: String,  completion:@escaping (Result<Bool, HTTPStatusCode>) -> Void){
        
        guard let url = URL(string:"http://localhost:8080/signup") else{
            fatalError("URL is not defined")
        }
        
        
        let user = User(account: account, password: password, confirmPassword: confirmPassword)
        
        var request=URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(user)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){
            data, response, error in
            
            if let _ = response{
                completion(.failure((HTTPStatusCode(rawValue: 400)!)))
            }else{
                completion(.success((HTTPStatusCode(rawValue: 200) != nil)))
            }
            
            
            
            
            
        }.resume()
    }
```

And I call the saveUser func in my view below. If the condition is success than I turn my is login In = true

```
private func saveUser(){
                HTTPUser().saveUser(account: number, password: pass, confirmPassword: repass){result in
                    switch result{
                    case .success(true):
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                            self.isLoggedIn = true
                        }
                    case .failure(_):
                        print(isLoggedIn)
                    case .success(false):
                        self.isLoggedIn = true
                    }
                }
            }
```

But the result didn't work . I know my code is such a mess. But I don't really know where to fix.And this is my http status code found on https://gist.github.com/ollieatkinson/322338df8a5220d649ac01ff11e7de12

```
enum HTTPStatusCode: Int, Error {
    
    /// The response class representation of status codes, these get grouped by their first digit.
    enum ResponseType {
        
        /// - informational: This class of status code indicates a provisional response, consisting only of the Status-Line and optional headers, and is terminated by an empty line.
        case informational
        
        /// - success: This class of status codes indicates the action requested by the client was received, understood, accepted, and processed successfully.
        case success
        
        /// - redirection: This class of status code indicates the client must take additional action to complete the request.
        case redirection
        
        /// - clientError: This class of status code is intended for situations in which the client seems to have erred.
        case clientError
        
        /// - serverError: This class of status code indicates the server failed to fulfill an apparently valid request.
        case serverError
        
        /// - undefined: The class of the status code cannot be resolved.
        case undefined
    }
    
    //
    // Informational - 1xx
    //
    
    /// - continue: The server has received the request headers and the client should proceed to send the request body.
    case `continue` = 100
    
    /// - switchingProtocols: The requester has asked the server to switch protocols and the server has agreed to do so.
    case switchingProtocols = 101
    
    /// - processing: This code indicates that the server has received and is processing the request, but no response is available yet.
    case processing = 102
    
    //
    // Success - 2xx
    //
    
    /// - ok: Standard response for successful HTTP requests.
    case ok = 200
    
    /// - created: The request has been fulfilled, resulting in the creation of a new resource.
    case created = 201
    
    /// - accepted: The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.
    case accepted = 202
    
    /// - nonAuthoritativeInformation: The server is a transforming proxy (e.g. a Web accelerator) that received a 200 OK from its origin, but is returning a modified version of the origin's response.
    case nonAuthoritativeInformation = 203
    
    /// - noContent: The server successfully processed the request and is not returning any content.
    case noContent = 204
    
    /// - resetContent: The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content.
    case resetContent = 205
    
    /// - partialContent: The server is delivering only part of the resource (byte serving) due to a range header sent by the client.
    case partialContent = 206
    
    /// - multiStatus: The message body that follows is an XML message and can contain a number of separate response codes, depending on how many sub-requests were made.
    case multiStatus = 207
    
    /// - alreadyReported: The members of a DAV binding have already been enumerated in a previous reply to this request, and are not being included again.
    case alreadyReported = 208
    
    /// - IMUsed: The server has fulfilled a request for the resource, and the response is a representation of the result of one or more instance-manipulations applied to the current instance.
    case IMUsed = 226
    
    //
    // Redirection - 3xx
    //
    
    /// - multipleChoices: Indicates multiple options for the resource from which the client may choose
    case multipleChoices = 300
    
    /// - movedPermanently: This and all future requests should be directed to the given URI.
    case movedPermanently = 301
    
    /// - found: The resource was found.
    case found = 302
    
    /// - seeOther: The response to the request can be found under another URI using a GET method.
    case seeOther = 303
    
    /// - notModified: Indicates that the resource has not been modified since the version specified by the request headers If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match.
    case notModified = 304
    
    /// - useProxy: The requested resource is available only through a proxy, the address for which is provided in the response.
    case useProxy = 305
    
    /// - switchProxy: No longer used. Originally meant "Subsequent requests should use the specified proxy.
    case switchProxy = 306
    
    /// - temporaryRedirect: The request should be repeated with another URI.
    case temporaryRedirect = 307
    
    /// - permenantRedirect: The request and all future requests should be repeated using another URI.
    case permenantRedirect = 308
    
    //
    // Client Error - 4xx
    //
    
    
    /// - badRequest: The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error.
    case badRequest = 400
    
    /// - unauthorized: Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been provided.
    case unauthorized = 401
    
    /// - paymentRequired: The content available on the server requires payment.
    case paymentRequired = 402
    
    /// - forbidden: The request was a valid request, but the server is refusing to respond to it.
    case forbidden = 403
    
    /// - notFound: The requested resource could not be found but may be available in the future.
    case notFound = 404
    
    /// - methodNotAllowed: A request method is not supported for the requested resource. e.g. a GET request on a form which requires data to be presented via POST
    case methodNotAllowed = 405
    
    /// - notAcceptable: The requested resource is capable of generating only content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.
    case notAcceptable = 406
    
    /// - proxyAuthenticationRequired: The client must first authenticate itself with the proxy.
    case proxyAuthenticationRequired = 407
    
    /// - requestTimeout: The server timed out waiting for the request.
    case requestTimeout = 408
    
    /// - conflict: Indicates that the request could not be processed because of conflict in the request, such as an edit conflict between multiple simultaneous updates.
    case conflict = 409
    
    /// - gone: Indicates that the resource requested is no longer available and will not be available again.
    case gone = 410
    
    /// - lengthRequired: The request did not specify the length of its content, which is required by the requested resource.
    case lengthRequired = 411
    
    /// - preconditionFailed: The server does not meet one of the preconditions that the requester put on the request.
    case preconditionFailed = 412
    
    /// - payloadTooLarge: The request is larger than the server is willing or able to process.
    case payloadTooLarge = 413
    
    /// - URITooLong: The URI provided was too long for the server to process.
    case URITooLong = 414
    
    /// - unsupportedMediaType: The request entity has a media type which the server or resource does not support.
    case unsupportedMediaType = 415
    
    /// - rangeNotSatisfiable: The client has asked for a portion of the file (byte serving), but the server cannot supply that portion.
    case rangeNotSatisfiable = 416
    
    /// - expectationFailed: The server cannot meet the requirements of the Expect request-header field.
    case expectationFailed = 417
    
    /// - teapot: This HTTP status is used as an Easter egg in some websites.
    case teapot = 418
    
    /// - misdirectedRequest: The request was directed at a server that is not able to produce a response.
    case misdirectedRequest = 421
    
    /// - unprocessableEntity: The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.
    case unprocessableEntity = 422
    
    /// - locked: The resource that is being accessed is locked.
    case locked = 423
    
    /// - failedDependency: The request failed due to failure of a previous request (e.g., a PROPPATCH).
    case failedDependency = 424
    
    /// - upgradeRequired: The client should switch to a different protocol such as TLS/1.0, given in the Upgrade header field.
    case upgradeRequired = 426
    
    /// - preconditionRequired: The origin server requires the request to be conditional.
    case preconditionRequired = 428
    
    /// - tooManyRequests: The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time.
    case tooManyRequests = 429
    
    /// - requestHeaderFieldsTooLarge: The server is unwilling to process the request because either an individual header field, or all the header fields collectively, are too large.
    case requestHeaderFieldsTooLarge = 431
    
    /// - noResponse: Used to indicate that the server has returned no information to the client and closed the connection.
    case noResponse = 444
    
    /// - unavailableForLegalReasons: A server operator has received a legal demand to deny access to a resource or to a set of resources that includes the requested resource.
    case unavailableForLegalReasons = 451
    
    /// - SSLCertificateError: An expansion of the 400 Bad Request response code, used when the client has provided an invalid client certificate.
    case SSLCertificateError = 495
    
    /// - SSLCertificateRequired: An expansion of the 400 Bad Request response code, used when a client certificate is required but not provided.
    case SSLCertificateRequired = 496
    
    /// - HTTPRequestSentToHTTPSPort: An expansion of the 400 Bad Request response code, used when the client has made a HTTP request to a port listening for HTTPS requests.
    case HTTPRequestSentToHTTPSPort = 497
    
    /// - clientClosedRequest: Used when the client has closed the request before the server could send a response.
    case clientClosedRequest = 499
    
    //
    // Server Error - 5xx
    //
    
    /// - internalServerError: A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable.
    case internalServerError = 500
    
    /// - notImplemented: The server either does not recognize the request method, or it lacks the ability to fulfill the request.
    case notImplemented = 501
    
    /// - badGateway: The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server.
    case badGateway = 502
    
    /// - serviceUnavailable: The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.
    case serviceUnavailable = 503
    
    /// - gatewayTimeout: The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.
    case gatewayTimeout = 504
    
    /// - HTTPVersionNotSupported: The server does not support the HTTP protocol version used in the request.
    case HTTPVersionNotSupported = 505
    
    /// - variantAlsoNegotiates: Transparent content negotiation for the request results in a circular reference.
    case variantAlsoNegotiates = 506
    
    /// - insufficientStorage: The server is unable to store the representation needed to complete the request.
    case insufficientStorage = 507
    
    /// - loopDetected: The server detected an infinite loop while processing the request.
    case loopDetected = 508
    
    /// - notExtended: Further extensions to the request are required for the server to fulfill it.
    case notExtended = 510
    
    /// - networkAuthenticationRequired: The client needs to authenticate to gain network access.
    case networkAuthenticationRequired = 511
    
    /// The class (or group) which the status code belongs to.
    var responseType: ResponseType {
        
        switch self.rawValue {
            
        case 100..<200:
            return .informational
            
        case 200..<300:
            return .success
            
        case 300..<400:
            return .redirection
            
        case 400..<500:
            return .clientError
            
        case 500..<600:
            return .serverError
            
        default:
            return .undefined
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

extension HTTPURLResponse {
    
    var status: HTTPStatusCode? {
        return HTTPStatusCode(rawValue: statusCode)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: guard let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
 return;
}
let statusCode = httpURLResponse.statusCode;
if statusCode == 200 {
 // success
}

Comment: Hey dude, it works!!! Thanks for helping. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that your line

```swift
if let _ = response {
```

will *always* be true if your endpoint returns anything. The only time it won't is if some error prevents your app from making a call in the first place.

The response object actually contains details of the response, including the HTTP status code returned by the server. To access it, you do need to cast the `URLResponse` type that's passed into the completion handler to its subclass, `HTTPURLResponse`. Casting to a subclass is always an optional cast, so it's wise to protect it within an `if let` clause:

```swift
if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
  print(response.statusCode) // 200, 404, etc...
}
```

From there, you should be able to determine whether to pass a failure or success back.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It seems that the current status code is assigned to response. But I don't actually know that how to "if" the response == status code 200